# PHP how do I get a formated result table of prepared statement as strings

Tags: php

I'm currently working on a small University project and I have to get into PHP. I have a score table where I want to get a ranked list back in PHP. The query works in phpmyadmin, but I just can't get my head around the prepared statement and how to get the results out of it. Here my code:

```
    $con = getConnection ();

if (!$con) {
    exit();
}

$stmt = $con -> prepare("SELECT NICKNAME, HIGHSCORE, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS RANK FROM scores p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY HIGHSCORE DESC;");

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result(); //$result is of type mysqli_result
$num_rows = $result->num_rows;  //count number of rows in the result

// the '=' in the if statement is intentional, it will return true on success or false if it fails.
if (!$result_array = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
}

for ($j=0; $j<=$num_rows ;$j++){
        $rows[$j]=$result->fetch_row();
        print_r($rows[$j]);
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

}

and this is how the print_r looks like:

> Array ( [0] => guvtg [1] => 234 [2] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => guvtgloa [1]
>   => 228 [2] => 3 ) Array ( [0] => guvtgloakkschmua [1] => 226 [2] => 4 ) Array ( [0] => guvtgloakk [1] => 182 [2] => 5 )

As you can see I'm getting the whole array, but I just want and output like this:

guvtg , 234 , 2
guvtgloa , 228 , 3
etc..

Does anybody know how to get a proper result? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `fetch_assoc()` it will give you an associative array with each item corresponding to a row field; will return FALSE when you are beyond the last row.

```
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
        echo $row[ 'NICKNAME' ] . "," . $row['HIGHSCORE'] . "," . $row['RANK'];
        // maybe echo something at the end of the line (another comma or a line break....)
}
```

You don't have to get the row count but you shoud check that `$result` is not `FALSE`.

Similarly if you don't care about column names you may use `fetch_row`

```
while ( $row = $result->fetch_row() ) {
        echo implode( ',', $row );
        // maybe echo something at the end of the line (another comma or a line break....)
}
```

This way you can use `implode` to pack the data in comma separated values.

(But you have to handle what character to put between each row in outout)

Ex. if you want rows separated by line breaks (that will produce a CSV file) put `echo "\n";` as the last statement inside the loop.

If you want a stream of comma separated values (no line breaks) then one solution is this:

```
$first = true;
while ( $row = $result->fetch_WOR() ) {
        if( $first ) { $first = false; } else { echo ","; }
        echo implode( ',', $row );
        // maybe echo something at the end of the line (another comma or a line break....)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much mr. pablo, it worked perfectly fine, I didn't know I could echo a single element of the array that way.

Comment: You're welcome. There are many ways to retrieve the result of a query and many ways to store or output it. Ex PHP has always `fetch_all()`. I just showed the most common...

Answer (score 1):

You'll allways get arrays from a database query, but it sounds like you just want to format the output differently. You could try this:

change

```
print_r($rows[$j]);
```

into

```
echo implode(', ', $rows[$j]), "\n";
```

`implode` will join the elements of every array with a comma+space in between, and by putting a newline after every record, the rows will each go on their own line.